# Identify the View that triggered a touch-event

Tags: android, view, touch

I am trying to drag a view over the screen

```
FrameLayout main = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_view);
final Ball bigball;
bigball = new Ball(this,50,50,25, 0xFFFF0000);
main.addView(bigball);
```

This draws a red circle on my screen. How and where do I need to implement my touchscreen-handling, if I want it *only* to trigger if someone touches the red circle rather than the remainder of the screen?

Ball.Java is a separate class:

```
public class Ball extends View
```

I know I could check the coordinates where the user touched the screen and then compare that to where the circle is, but there must be a way to simply check the ID or some other reference of the circle, right?

Everything I have looked at and tried so far would run my code regardless of where the touch started or stopped on the screen. (So I can move the ball, I can draw lines on the screen with my finger and everything. But I cannot tell if I touched the red circle.)

Can anyone expain this to me in simple words, please? (And forgive me for using equally simple words in my question. I no longer feel I have a clue what I'm doing here, and I by now I would just not use big words like "Listener" or "Event" correctly anymore.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can override/implement onTouchEvent in Ball class which is extended from View.

```
public class Ball extends View {
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if(ev.getAction == /*check against all the desired action*/ {
      //handle touch and return true
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Comment: But the function gets called regardless of where I click. Is it possible that my ball simply takes up the entire screen and I've been chasing the wrong type of error?

It's a ciclre drawn on a Canvas:

Comment: public class Ball extends View   {
     private  float x;
     private  float y;
     private final int r;
     private final Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
     
     public Ball(Context context, float x, float y, int r, int bcolor) {
         super(context);
         mPaint.setColor(bcolor);
         this.x = x;
         this.y = y;
         this.r = r;
     }
 
     @Override
     protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
         super.onDraw(canvas);
         canvas.drawCircle(x, y, r, mPaint);

Comment: where have you defined the functions and from where are you calling this function?

Comment: Okay, my mistake was that the canvas of the circle took up the entire screen. Everything worked fine - but I was only ever touching the circle-canvas and never the screen itself.

I have now used an ImageView and assigned setOnTouchListener to it in the main activity. Works like a charm.

Thank you!